# Can i remove default js/calendarview/calendarview.js?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

Can i remove the following inlined js and js/calendarview/calendarview.js from magento store?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
enUS = {"m":{"wide":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"abbr":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]}}; // en_US locale reference
Calendar._DN = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]; // full day names
Calendar._SDN = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"]; // short day names
Calendar._FD = 0; // First day of the week. "0" means display Sunday first, "1" means display Monday first, etc.
Calendar._MN = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]; // full month names
Calendar._SMN = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]; // short month names
Calendar._am = "AM"; // am/pm
Calendar._pm = "PM";

// tooltips
Calendar._TT = {};
Calendar._TT["INFO"] = 'About the calendar';

Calendar._TT["ABOUT"] =
'DHTML Date/Time Selector\n' +
"(c) dynarch.com 2002-2005 / Author: Mihai Bazon\n" +
'For latest version visit: http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/\n' +
'Distributed under GNU LGPL. See http://gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html for details.' +
'\n\n' +
'Date selection:\n' +
'- Use the \xab, \xbb buttons to select year\n' +
'- Use the \u2039 buttons to select month\n' +
'- Hold mouse button on any of the above buttons for faster selection.';
Calendar._TT["ABOUT_TIME"] = '\n\n' +
'Time selection:\n' +
'- Click on any of the time parts to increase it\n' +
'- or Shift-click to decrease it\n' +
'- or click and drag for faster selection.';

Calendar._TT["PREV_YEAR"] = 'Prev. year (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["PREV_MONTH"] = 'Prev. month (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["GO_TODAY"] = 'Go Today';
Calendar._TT["NEXT_MONTH"] = 'Next month (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["NEXT_YEAR"] = 'Next year (hold for menu)';
Calendar._TT["SEL_DATE"] = 'Select date';
Calendar._TT["DRAG_TO_MOVE"] = 'Drag to move';
Calendar._TT["PART_TODAY"] = ' (' + "today" + ')';

// the following is to inform that "%s" is to be the first day of week
Calendar._TT["DAY_FIRST"] = 'Display %s first';

// This may be locale-dependent. It specifies the week-end days, as an array
// of comma-separated numbers. The numbers are from 0 to 6: 0 means Sunday, 1
// means Monday, etc.
Calendar._TT["WEEKEND"] = "0,6";

Calendar._TT["CLOSE"] = 'Close';
Calendar._TT["TODAY"] = "today";
Calendar._TT["TIME_PART"] = '(Shift-)Click or drag to change value';

// date formats
Calendar._TT["DEF_DATE_FORMAT"] = "%b %e, %Y";
Calendar._TT["TT_DATE_FORMAT"] = "%B %e, %Y";

Calendar._TT["WK"] = "Week";
Calendar._TT["TIME"] = 'Time:';
//]]>
</script>
```

I am using gmetais/unuedjs tool to find unused default js.
It's showing that js/calendarview/calendarview.js is not used, but the above inlined js uses its function (so i will need to remove both of them).

I am wondering where and when exactly this date settings/scripts are used by magento, and if they can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JS `js/calendarview/calendarview.js` exist in default magento. Please tell complete version of your Magento.

Although **to find the uses of any JS in magento** you can search in layout section for frontend & backend.

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout
```